# Run Django tests before commit with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, continuous-integration, automated-tests, django-tests

Is it possible to configure the PyCharm commit dialog to run Django test configurations prior to commit?

The commit dialog in my installation (Windows 10, 2021.3 Professional) only seems to detect Python test configurations.

Images below show all configured tests, and the tests available to the commit dialog.

[image: Django & Python Test Configuration]
[image: Git Commit Dialog - Python Test configurations only]

Comment: Did you ever solve this? just ran into the same thing

Comment: Leaving a comment to see if it gets addressed.